# Access main template from submodule

Tags: scala, web, playframework, playframework-2.0, sbt

I have a Play2 project with submodule and structure like following:

```
+ app
  + models
  + controllers
  + views
    + index.scala.html
    + main.scala.html
+ conf
+ modules
  + frontend
    + app
      + controllers
      + views
        + page.scala.html
```

Module enabled in build.sbt and both root module and frontend module works as I expected and even controller URLs from both modules can be reversed within each other.

But I can't invoke `main.scala.html` template from my `page.scala.html`.
When I try to invoke it as usual (`@main(title) { ...`) I got a compilation error: `not found: value main`.
What is the right path would be here for a main template?

Upd. I think it should be a SBT-addressed problem. My build.sbt is looks like this

```
name := """myproject"""

version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

lazy val frontend = (project in file("modules/frontend")).enablePlugins(PlayScala)

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayScala).aggregate(frontend).dependsOn(frontend)

scalaVersion := "2.11.4"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.postgresql" % "postgresql" % "9.3-1102-jdbc41",
  jdbc,
  anorm,
  cache,
  ws
)

pipelineStages := Seq(rjs, digest, gzip)
```

Comment: I'm afraid you cannot do this, since the frontend project knows nothing about the root, and you can't have circular module dependencies. Views (and anything else) common to modules need to be in a sub-project _on which those modules depend_. In my Play app the root/main project is really just a stub containing the app `Global`.

Comment: @Mikesname yep. I've already came to this conclusion. Very unusual after dynamic python world. You may post it as an answer, I'll mark it as solution.

Comment: it can initially be a bit frustrating working within the limitations of sub-module dependencies, especially where [reverse routes](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues/1390) are concerned. But I suppose it does force you to keep things neatly partitioned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sub-projects can only use their own resources or those in projects on which they depend (via `.dependsOn`). Since your frontend project does not depend on the root project it can't make use of its view templates (nor can you have a circular dependency between sub-projects.)

The only solution in this case is to move the view `main.scala.html` template into the frontend module, or create a "common" module as a base dependency for the frontend (and potentially other sub-projects) to use.